# Is there a way to bypass some of the iOS wizard screens for eSIM configuration?

Tags: ios, wizard, cellular-network, carrier

I'm developing an app that should install an eSIM by demand of the user. The problem is that iOS wizard screens are really bad for user experience. Our testings showed that almost 90% of participants were confused by those screens, specifically the Label and default line ones. Since those screens have an option to be configured later, is there anyway to bypass them initially?

The only way so far to activate and request an eSIM from the carrier is the addPlan instance method from Core Telephony framework, which it only states that the output would be "Once your app calls this method, an iOS wizard guides the user through the process of installing and configuration an eSIM."

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretelephony/ctcellularplanprovisioning/2981838-addplan

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution to that?

Comment: Could you maybe take a look at an open question relating esim I have as well? I'm just starting with eSIM, have the proper entitlements but for some reason not able to make the functions work properly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58630606/coretelephony-esim-functions-not-working-on-device