# CoreTelephony eSIM functions not working on device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, provisioning-profile, core-telephony

I've been having some trouble implementing eSIM into an existing iOS carrier-application.

**The setup**

- The app has received the `public-cellular-plan` entitlement which I
  understand is the entitlement giving me access to the eSIM functions
  of CoreTelephony.
- I've imported the CoreTelephony framework in the app's target: `General > Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content` which is marked as `Do not Embed`, same as other frameworks like CoreData and such.
- I've imported the library in the class making the calls `import CoreTelephony`
- I'm running a development build with the correct profile via Xcode on an iPhone XR, which has a data plan active so I'm sure it supports it.

**The problem**
Supposedly with all this, I should now have access to the eSIM functions like `supportsCellularPlan` but unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working:

```
let provisioning = CTCellularPlanProvisioning()
let supportsESIM = provisioning.supportsCellularPlan()

print("\(supportsESIM)") 
// This prints false but should be true as the XR supports eSIM
```

I've also tried via TestFlight with the distribution profile but same result.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I am also having the same issue, any update?

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution to this? I am having the same issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So... after a lot of trial an error I was able to solve this little issue.

There are 2 things to know about `supportsCellularPlan()` (other then having the eSIM entitlements of course).

First:
You need to have WiFi enabled for it to work as it seems to need to connect with Apple for some checks.

Second:
It requires the `CarrierDescriptors` to be entered correctly in your `info.plist` as it is carrier-bound.

Once you have that, it should work as expected.

Comment: If we ever cross paths I owe you a beer

Comment: I'll remember that ;)

Comment: what is CarrierDescriptors. can you please share me the sample CarrierDescriptors which we need to place in info.plist @Thomas

Comment: @nareshkolindala The CarrierDescriptors is a dictionary of unique codes given by your Carrier that identify them on the network. You should check with them for these codes.

Comment: @Thomas could you please, give a example what should it be looked in info.plist?

Answer (score 0):

CarrierDescriptors Example:

```
  <key>CarrierDescriptors</key>
    <array>
      <dict> 
      <key>MCC</key> //Mobile country code
       <string>’mnc value’</string>
       <key>MNC</key> // Mobile network code
        <string>’mnc value’</string>
      </dict>
    </array>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the correct MCC/MNC values here: https://www.mcc-mnc.com
Btw for some reason, it also works for me, when there is just random value "xxx" for example.
But it needs to be there in the plist.